# How to create Search Box under my pagination using Golang Echo framework

Tags: html, go, echo, searchbar

```
// Get page number from path `product/:page`
        pageNumber := c.Param("page")
        page, err := strconv.Atoi(pageNumber)
        if err != nil || page < 1 {
            page = 1
        }

        // set pageSize to 10 for now
        pageSize := 10

        offset := (page - 1) * pageSize

        // get the rows paginated by offset
        rows, err := database.WrapQuery(dbconnections.DBPool, ctx, "GetFromProductPaginatedByOffset", pageSize, offset)
        if err != nil {
            loggerWithTrace.Error().Err(err).Caller().Msg("database.WrapQuery error")
        }
        defer rows.Close()

        results := make([]models.Product, 0)

        for rows.Next() {
            var data models.Product
            err := rows.Scan(&data.Prefix, &data.Suffix, &data.Usage)
            if err != nil {
                loggerWithTrace.Error().Err(err).Caller().Msg("database.WrapQuery error")
            }
            results = append(results, data)
        }

        // Get the total item of product 
        var totalItems int
        err = database.WrapQueryRow(dbconnections.DBPool, ctx, "GetTotalSizeFromProduct").Scan(&totalItems)
        if err != nil {
            loggerWithTrace.Error().Err(err).Caller().Msg("database.WrapQueryRow error")
        }

        totalPages := totalItems / pageSize
        nextPage := page + 1
        prevPage := page - 1

        templateDataMap["DataMap"] = DataMap
        templateDataMap["Product"] = results
        templateDataMap["Page"] = page
        templateDataMap["PageSize"] = pageSize
        templateDataMap["TotalItems"] = totalItems
        templateDataMap["PageItemCount"] = pageSize
        templateDataMap["TotalPages"] = totalPages
        templateDataMap["NextPage"] = nextPage
        templateDataMap["PrevPage"] = prevPage

        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "product", templateDataMap)
```

**Here is my pagination code in handler,
**//more code here to connect with login and cookies

**Here is my sql
**Q_GET_PAGINATION_FROM_PRODUCT = `SELECT * FROM PRODUCT where (prefix like '%%%s%%' or "usage" like '%%%s%%') LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2`
Q_GET_FROM_PRODUCT_TOTAL_SIZE = `SELECT count(*) FROM PRODUCT`

**Here is my route
**PATH_PAGINATE_PRODUCT = PATH + "/product/:page"

e.GET(PATH_PAGINATE_PRODUCT, handlers.Product)

`

I tried to create search box/ search query but it didnt seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

In **LIKE** operator of SQL query for "prefix" and "usage", You must pass an argument as this example below

```
//... some logic
// change your request like this
prefix = "%"+data.Prefix+"%"
usage = "%"+data.Usage+"%"
```

And then your SQL query must change to this

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT where (prefix like '%s' or "usage" like '%s') LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2
```